AWS Lambda timing out when sending email with SMTP
I'm trying to use AWS Lambda and API gateway to add a "Contact Me" page on my static portfolio website. I've added API Gateway as a trigger for my Lambda function, which is sent a POST request from my website when a user submits a contact form.
I'm trying to send an email to myself from the Lambda function with the data in the submitted contact form. This is my handler -
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import json
import os
import smtplib, ssl

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = json.loads(event['body'])
    if 'name' in request and 'email' in request and 'message' in request:
        sent_from = '[my email]'
        gmail_password = os.environ.get('GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD')
        sent_to = '[my other email]'
        message = request['message']
        subject = request['subject'] if 'subject' in request else f'Message from {user_name}'

        message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        message['Subject'] = subject
        message['From'] = sent_from
        message['To'] = sent_to


        body = f"""
            [my email body]
        """
        part1 = MIMEText(body, 'html')
        message.attach(part1)

        try:
            context = ssl.create_default_context()
            with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as server:
                server.login(sent_from, gmail_password)
                server.sendmail(sent_from, sent_to, message.as_string())
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps(True)
            }
        except Exception as e:
            return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'body': str(e)
            }
    return {
        'statusCode': 400,
        'body': '{"message": "Bad Request"}'
    }

I've verified that my code works correctly upto the server.login(sent_from, gmail_password) line. I am able to log in successfully. However, some error occurs on the server.sendmail() line, which returns a generic HTTP 500 response (not the one returned by my except block, because I don't see the exception message in the response).
I looked at the CloudWatch logs for my function, and it seems like it must be timing out, as I see this -

Sometimes I even get the email in my inbox but with no subject or body.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
